# JIRA - User changes history

Tags: jira

Is there a way to view who made permission changes to a JIRA user?

I am a JIRA administrator but someone else removed certain permissions for my User in a Project. I want to know who did it.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

As an administrator, you can see the history of all user permission changes in [the Audit Log](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/auditing-in-jira-applications-938847740.html).

In the Audit Log, you can filter for events marked `User management` to see all changes to user permissions.